# How can I NOT create an element in HTML whenon mobile?

Tags: html, css

I want to display a tabl1 in a different place depending on whether app is being viewd on PC screen or mobile.

The code below ALMOST does this except it tries to create 2 Pulse2Tables, one hidden, one not. I need a table with this specific name because it is updated later.

Is there an alternative where I can tell CSS not to create table as opposed to just hiding it?

```css
.MobileContent {
  display: none;
}

@@media only screen and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .MobileContent {
    display:block;
  }
}

.ScreenContent {
  display: block;
}

@@media only screen and (max-device-width: 667px) and (orientation: portrait) {
  .ScreenContent {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="ScreenContent" style="padding: 0px;height:100%;">
  <table id="Pulse2Table" class="display2" style="position:absolute;top:5px;left:185px;height:100%">
    <tbody id="Pulse2Body" style="height:100%">
    <tbody>
  </table>
</span>


<span class="MobileContent" style="padding: 0px;height:100%;">
  <table id="Pulse2Table" class="display2" style="position:absolute;top:5px;left:185px;height:100%">
    <tbody id="Pulse2Body" style="height:100%">
    <tbody>
  </table>
</span>
```

Comment: duplicating id#Pulse2Table is a error. And @@media has a plus @, remove it-

Comment: @Roy a second @ is required for RAZOR. Double Pulse2Table is the error I am trying to fix!